# Find the video card information on the command line

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics

I am trying to find the basic information (name, version) of the video driver(s) (which graphic cards are present) on a Linux machine (version 2.6.9).

I've tried these commands:

```
lspci
lshw
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
/sys
lsmod
update-pciids
modinfo
```

but they all came out as `Command not found.`

Without installing any new tools, is there a way to get the information I'm looking for?

Comment: Are you trying to find which graphics card(s) are present, or which driver(s) a GUI session is currently using?

Comment: Which graphic cards are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

In EL4 the lspci command is /sbin/lspci . Commands in /sbin/, /usr/sbin/ can be run as root only. The same for lsmod, IIRR.

'lshw' is always an extra package : /sbin/lshw

'update-pciids' is available from a third party package.

Note : The old RHEL 4 (kernel 2.6.9) Was released 2005, and supported until 2011.

---

Comment: Yup. /sbin/lspci is giving me what I need. Thanks!